# The Distribution of a Function of a Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a PDF of $X$:

$f(x; \alpha) = k/x^\alpha$ , for $x\ge5$, and $0$ for all else.

And $\ln(X/5)$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\alpha-1$

My question is what exactly is $\ln(X/5)$ when $X$ already has a distribution? Is this essentially a $g(f(x))$ situation where I plug the pdf equation of $X$ into $\ln(x/5)$?

I know $E(g(x))$ is $\int g(x)f(x)\,dx$, but I'm not interested in the expected value. I just want to know the intuition of using the random variable $X$ as a parameter for another function such as $\ln(X/5)$

Comment: Please: look at the typographical difference between $\alpha$-1 and $\alpha-1$.  I fixed that and a bunch of other things. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics, a function is a mapping of some number to some other number. In the case of $\ln\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)$ it is a mapping from $\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$.

It makes no difference if the function is acting on:

- a deterministic known number (like $3.25$)
- a deterministic unknown number (like $x$)
- an indeterminate unknown number (like $X$)

Algebra is algebra.

It may help if you think about more familiar PDF, like $U(0,1)$, and a simpler function, like $2x$. What do you get if you apply the function to the pdf? $U(0,2)$, right?

Comment: So it acts on the values of input? Not on the distribution itself? Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Yes, No & Yes/No. It acts on the values of the input, the input is the distribution. I visualize the distribution as a quantum particle - we have a probabilistic notion of its "location" - the function acts on this "location" to give us a new "location". That's because I'm an engineer not a mathematician.

Comment: Could you demonstrate in my example on how ln(x/5) would make X into an exponential distribution?

Comment: Have you posted the entire question - there is info missing to get the result you seek